# Is there a web-based log-tailing application?

Tags: logging

I have been using BareTail for low-footprint log reading, and it works wonderfully. In particular, I like that it can consume very large large files, detect changes to those files, all without consuming much memory at all.

I'd like to know if there are applications out there -- flash, java applet, etc -- that I could use in a web page to mimic this functionality in a program I'm writing

Comment: maybe you could ask this over at serverfault?

Comment: Not sure I understand how a question about a program I can use as a programmer in a web page has anything to do with server fault. I'm asking this as a programmer looking to build an application, not as a system administrator doing system-admin stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this client-side only, the tailing of the logfile has to be done on the server.

Here's an example in [Python](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/155/) that's using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Check vsConsole http://www.vamonossoftware.com/vsconsole

Comment: vsConsole is a web application that you can run in Tomcat. You can install small agents on multiple servers which are configured to expose certain log files on the servers. From vsConsole, you can now see those files and tail them. Also allows you to see the status (up/down) of your applications, and if you want, what version they are.

Answer (score 1):

This now possible thanks to ColdFusion 10 and Web sockets.

Checkout this blog post for info. 
http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2012/3/13/Websockets-demo-Log-Watcher

:)